# Looking for a program similar to Alfred and Keyboard Maestro

Tags: keyboard

Despite Alfred and Keyboard Maestro being able to trigger many things by shortcut, they both require you to use a modifier and key to work. Though Alfred does support a double tap of shift, option and command, it appears to stop there.
x
What I'd like is an application to detect patterns like:
double tap command followed by a double tap of option. Which then opens whatever you choose.

Anyone know if such application exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't figure out any way to do that with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html), but this would make pressing command twice and then pressing option open Finder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
     <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_FINDER</name>
     <url>file:///System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__DoublePressModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
    KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::VK_STICKY_EXTRA1</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1,
    KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_FINDER</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml or http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more examples.

Comment: Excellent idea (and example). I do use KeyRemap4Macbook often but it never occurred to me to use it for double tap combinations. Truly a wonderful application.

Comment: There are a few [articles](http://elasticthreads.tumblr.com/post/3627610765/put-your-macs-caps-lock-key-to-better-use) out there about using the caps lock key to trigger Alfred. Depending on how much you'll use caps lock... might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard Maestro can do this in a number of ways.  An entirely extensible way is to make a sequence of self-disabling macros, something like this:

```
Macro: First Command Key
Trigger: Device Key Command Key
Actions:
Disable Macro "First Command Key"
Enable "Second Command Key"
Pause 3 Seconds <- adjust as necessary
Disable Macro "Second Command Key"
Enable Macro "First Command Key"
```

and then

```
Macro: Second Command Key
Trigger: Device Key Command Key
Actions:
Disable Macro "Second Command Key"
Enable "Second Command First Option Key"
Pause 3 Seconds <- adjust as necessary
Disable Macro "Second Command First Option Key"
```

and then

```
Macro: Second Command First Option Key
Trigger: Device Key Option Key
Actions:
Disable Macro "Second Command First Option Key"
Enable "Second Command Second Option Key"
Pause 3 Seconds <- adjust as necessary
Disable Macro "Second Command Second Option Key"
```

and then

```
Macro: Second Command Second Option Key
Trigger: Device Key Option Key
Actions:
Disable Macro "Second Command Second Option Key"
Perform whatever actions desired.
```

etc

It'll take a couple minutes to set up, but you can configure it any way you like.

Answer (score -1):

Just as a direction, as I don't really have time to make sure this does what you want. Typinator (http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/features.html) is a keystroke replacement program that can also run scripts. So you can in theory set any combination of keys to trigger a script and that in turn could open a program, take over the world or whatever. Might be worth a shot.